# Local vs. Global Parameters? In a Launch File?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

What is the difference between setting a parameter in a launch file like this (i.e. outside of a node tag):

```
<param name="param01" value="value01" />
<node name="node01" pkg="package01" type="node01" />
```

and this (i.e. wrapped inside of a node tag):

```
<node name="node01" pkg="package01" type="node01">
      <param name="param01" value="value01" />
</node>
```

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12094/local-vs.-global-parameters?-in-a-launch-file?/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first example defines a ["relative" name](http://ros.org/wiki/Names#Resolving).

The second defines a ["private" parameter](http://ros.org/wiki/Parameter%20Server#Private_Parameters).

Most ROS nodes look for parameters in their private namespace, so the second is generally preferred. But, there are sometimes reasons to define parameters at a higher level, as in the first example.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-25**:
It's relative, not global. When pushed into a namespace it will not be at the top level anymore (unless you use the /). When using the second variant, the parameters are private without the ~ already.

**Comment by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on 2011-11-25**:
Would the top parameter also be considered a global? Also, does that mean that private param names should always start with "~" and global with "/" (following the link you provided)?